# What does this error mean? ([Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The LEVEL clause includes a reserved word...)

Tags: sql, excel-2007

Full error message: "[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The LEVEL clause includes a reserved word or argument that is mispelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect"

I get this when trying to execute a query in one excel document against a table in another excel document. My SQL doesn't include LEVEL at all, and I can't find anything useful on Google.

Before anyone asks: Yes, I know excel isn't a database. I can't find a better way to get this data from sheet to sheet.

Because I like my job, I've obfuscated my SQL; otherwise it includes company confidential data. I am certain that my syntax is right on the things that I am removing, because it was written my Microsoft Query.

```
SELECT `Table1$`.`Field1`, <Other Fields from Table1>,
 `Table2$`.`FieldA`, <Other Fields from Table2>,
 `Table3$`.`FieldX`,
 `Table3$`.`FieldY`
FROM `<network path starting with \\>\<filename>.xlsb`.`Table1$` `Table1$`,
 `<network path starting with \\>\<filename>.xlsb`.`Table2$` `Table2$`,
 `<network path starting with \\>\<filename>.xlsb`.`Table3$` `Table3$`
WHERE `Table2$`.`Join1Field` = `Table1$`.`Join1Field`
 AND `Table3$`.`Join2Field` = `Table1$`.`Join2Field`
 AND `Table1$`.`Weeks Ago` < 14;
```

Note: All of these tables are in the same Excel file, and I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you post a question about an error that you can't identify, changing to things like `<other fields from>` and `<network path starting with \\>` makes it impossible to help you. You've removed content that may be the problem. Instead, try listing the actual `other fields`, anonymizing only specific things enough to make them anonymous, and including as much of `<network path>` as you can as well. Since your question specifically mentions `reserved words` and you've removed some of the `words`, how can we help?

Comment: Is there any login security in the picture that might involve something called "access level"? If so, change the label "access level" to something without the word "level" and without a space. (Just a guess based on a web search for "The LEVEL clause includes a reserved word".)

Comment: Don't you need to use "as" when aliasing your tables?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page on MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/HV080761273.aspx) you entered an SQL statement that has an invalid reserved word or incorrect punctuation. As @Ken White points out, it's hard to tell from your edited SQL what is going on.

IIRC when you use the GUI tool in MS Query it writes ODBC syntax: perhaps there is a problem in translation to native Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) syntax at the Excel end. If you can write SQL without GUI tools, or can use the Access QBE thing to do it for you, IIRC you can paste native Access SQL syntax into MS Query's SQL window and it will 'pass through' to Excel unchanged.